# Which script or method execute eclipse when I use export bundle?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

We are developing a project using `OSGi framework`. To make the bundle we use the export function of eclipse (`Export->Plug-in Development->Deployable plug-ins and fragments`). Since we have a lot of bundles (more then 50) is there a possibility to get the script or method used by eclipse for building the bundle? I'm not sure but I think it use `Ant`, I've searched into eclipse repo but I found nothing about that

Answer (score 0):

So, you are using PDE to export your bundle. 
I would take a look at the Equinox P2 Publisher, and to the PDE build extensions to that publisher.

- https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Publisher
- http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_p2_buildtasks.htm

Keep in mind I already produced some build with PDE, but I chose to switch to Tycho. In this case I would consider to convert the export task using Maven / Tycho. See

- http://www.slideshare.net/TeodorMadan/migrating-from-pde-to-tycho-builds
- http://codeandme.blogspot.fr/2012/12/tycho-build-5-building-p2-update-sites.html

Then you could use the tycho P2 publisher.

- https://eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-p2/tycho-p2-publisher-plugin/plugin-info.html

Note: this solution was outlined in #eclipse IRC, see:
http://echelog.com/logs/browse/eclipse/1441749600

Comment: It's our decision to not use maven

Comment: So I would consider the PDE equivalent. 
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_p2_buildtasks.htm

Please see edited answer, and share feedback !